# Convergence based on sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

i trouble with the following question:

We have $ X_n := a_n|x|$ where X is normal-distributed, plus the variable is defined via a second random variable Z, which is uniformly distributed on (0,1), with $Z \leq b_n$ and $a_n, b_n > 0 $ and $b_n \leq 1$
So, to put this a bit more clearly:
$X_n:= a_n |x|1_{z\leq b_n}$ where 1 stands for the characteristic function.

Those are the conditions given.
Question is: Give Conditions for $a_n, b_n$, so that $X_n$:
converges in probability,
converges almost certain,
converges in distribution,
$L^P$ converges,

Well about my own ideas:
the thing i noticed is, that i can skip the convergence in probability, since it follows out of the other two.
My problem is that i dont have any idea on how to tackle this, so any help is much appreciated

thanks